# APK app project not pulling aar transitive deps

Tags: android, gradle, aar, transitive-dependency

I have an android library project with this gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

group 'com.test'
version '0.0.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.sdk"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Then I have an application with this build script:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.test:sdk:0.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

I am using a maven plugin to publish my libraries sdk to my local maven repository:
https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-plugin

I run the install task on my library project and it successfully publishes the library .aar along with the pom file.  The pom file lists gson as a compile dependency.

Generated POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run my application I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError's for the gson classes.  Looking through the apk I do not see the gson dep pulled in at all.

I have read that putting the extension '@aar' on the dependency sets transitive to false and does not pull the transitive dependencies.  So I added transitive = true.  I have also tried it without the '@aar' extension and I run into the same problem.

I am using Android Studio RC1 w/ gradle plugin version 0.14.4.

Comment: `@aar` should definitely be omitted. It's only necessary when no pom.xml exists for the module. Can you show the pom.xml?

Comment: Added generated pom file

Comment: That pom doesn't list gson as a dependency.

Comment: Sorry, wrong pom file.  I promise its not that easy.

Comment: I don't see any repository declarations in your build scripts.

Comment: Found it, and it was dumb ;)  I have a class that extends Application, I am building mutlidex and that class needs to extend MutliDexApplication.  Dex files were built but app could handle multiple.  Imagine NoClassDefFound errors were from classes that were build into other dex files.  DOH!

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Is the gson jar pulled in your apk?